# What was the expected retirement age for men in Spain in 1936?

Tags: economy, social-history, spain, 1930s, great-depression

I am trying to find out what the expected age of retirement was for men in Spain in 1936.

I tried searching the Internet but the results I found were for recent years and not time past.

Comment: [Articles 46-47](http://production.clinecenter.illinois.edu/REPOSITORYCACHE/30/Q5yIX5tC8600tRU2W626ZMl50lZBw60Lh1f87D7C8Pw62oP797cB900ax15KOQ4USxKCS3zEFI97LguMwL8S8IIKWOR8nd2cUcuNyiAvp33_19231.pdf) of the [Spanish constitution of 1931-9](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spanish_Constitution_of_1931) might be a good place to start.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In the [Ley del Retiro Obrero](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Retiro_Obrero) from 1919, the age for retirement of workers was established at **65 years**.

The Law was applied from 1923 on, but it was criticized [by the patrons](https://www.abc.es/historia/abci-jubilacion-anos-pension-peseta-201101270000_noticia.html) and the high corruption made the Second Republic (1931-1936) to develop [a different law](https://maldita.es/malditobulo/20201120/franco-creo-seguridad-social/), which wasn't finished due to the Spanish Civil War (1936-1939).

Members of the army got special ages of retirement in 1931 through the [Law for the Reform of the Army](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reforma_militar_de_Manuel_Aza%C3%B1a).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In this case I am looking at someone who retired at 54 years of age and worked all his life in the Civil Guard up to retirement. So your last sentence has peaked my attention even more.

Comment: @AndrewTruckle Oh, for sure: the Guardia Civil is a military police force. The age of retirement of your relative would have depended on the amount of years working and (specially) on the charge he attained. For some officers, 54-56 years old was common.

Comment: At the time of his retirement he was in the first class.

Comment: @AndrewTruckle I checked it (Gaceta de Madrid, 27th April 1931) and he could have asked for the retirement at 52 years old, although, according to the historian Michael Alpert, only 46% of the officers of his class retired so early.

Comment: Beware that even in recent times retired military and retired Guardia Civil officers could work in other fields.